# Can JSON file get its own path (access its own properties)?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file which points to other files in its directory.

e.g.

```
{
   "resinSettingsFile": "C:/Users/patryk/Desktop/settings_xkelet_magna-350/assets/resins/High_Tensile_Translucent_350um.resin.json"
}
```

this file in in `C:/Users/patryk/Desktop/settings_xkelet_magna-350 but this directory can be moved which would result in C:/Users/patryk/Desktop/` no longer being applicable in the object above.

So my question is, can I somehow replace that `C:/Users/patryk/Desktop/` with something that points to the absolute path of the `settings_xkelet_magna-350 directory` wherever it might be at the time?

I guess I'm looking for something like this:

```
{
   "resinSettingsFile": thisFileDirectory + "/assets/resins/High_Tensile_Translucent_350um.resin.json"
}
```

where `thisFileDirector` would either be the actual location propertie of the file or something to tell the JavaScript that is going to process it to take the location of this json file directory.

Comment: No, there is nothing like that in JSON. You would need to code something where you use the file to know the path of where you grabbed the file and how to alter he URLS.

Comment: Makes sense, I have another way but I think it would be pretty handy if json file could access its own properties and use them in its content. Thanks for input nonetheless! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @epascarello answered:
"No, there is nothing like that in JSON. You would need to code something where you use the file to know the path of where you grabbed the file and how to alter he URLS"